# How to get a specific value from a MongoDb document

Tags: database, mongodb, linq, iqueryable, bson

I am trying to get a specific value from a Bson document using an IQueryable object. I have a method that is reading a json structure as shown below.

```
"SimulatedData": [
    {
      "value": 1819.00923045901,
      "units": "hp",
      "tag": "comp/totalIhp",
      "name": "Compressor - Total IHP"
    },
{
      "value": 789.294125,
      "units": "RPM",
      "tag": "comp/averageSpeed",
      "name": "Compressor - Speed"
    },
    {
      "value": 2064.74658240481,
      "units": "hp",
      "tag": "comp/totalBhp",
      "name": "Compressor - Total BHP"
    }
]
```

I am reading this JSON, getting the 'tag' key value and then looking for this tag value in a collection in MongoDB.

```
try
            {
                string jsonFromFile;
                using (var reader = new StreamReader(path))
                {
                    jsonFromFile = reader.ReadToEnd();
                }

                var simulatedData = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(jsonFromFile);

                foreach (var channel in simulatedData.SimulatedData)
                {
                    var tag = channel.tag;

                    var master = DBConnect.CosmosClient.GetCollection<MasterVariables>("MasterVariables");

                    var channelId = master.AsQueryable().Where(x => x.Tag == $"{tag}");


                    foreach(var c in channelId)
                    {
                        string id = c.ChannelID;
                        Console.WriteLine(id);
                    }
                }
            }
```

The value of the 'tag' key will be used to search in MasterVariables for a match. The document in MasterVariables that matches the value of the 'tag' key will result in a JSON/bson as below.I have a class that take in these values and sets them to class attributes

```
  {
        "Tag" : "comp/idealTotalSucCapacity",
        "Group" : "{ id : \"comp\", parent : \"#\", text : \"Compressor\" }",
        "Series" : "Compressor",
        "Enabled" : true,
        "ChannelID" : "C8",
        "productType" : "Spotlight_Comp",
        "database" : "compdata"
    }
```

MasterVariables class (below)

```
public class MasterVariables
        {
            public string Tag { get; set; }
            public string Group { get; set; }
            public string Series { get; set; }
            public bool Enabled { get; set; }
            public string ChannelID { get; set; }
            public string productType { get; set; }
            public string database { get; set; }
        }
```

My main issue is that I am not able to get the "ChannelID" value using `c.ChannelID` . My code compiles and doesn't give me any errors. But I am very confused as to why I am not able to get the channelID value using an Iqueryable object. I know the below `foreach` isn't correct since I will only be receiving 1 Bson document that matches the 'tag' value. But I haven't found anything helpful about a different way to get the ChannelId. Any thoughts on what I am doing wrong here? Or is there a different approach?

```
 foreach(var c in channelId)
   {
     string id = c.ChannelID;
     Console.WriteLine(id);
   }
```

Comment: Are you using MongoDB or CosmosDB?

Comment: I am using MongoDb

Comment: Your code shows reference to CosmosClient - `DBConnect.CosmosClient.`  ?

Comment: Do you get any other string fields - like `Tag`, or `Group` in the `foreach`?

Comment: Not sure why there is a reference to cosmos. But when i remove that part of the code i get errors. And no  i do not get any other fields in the foreach loop

Comment: So IQueryable is deferred execution.  Could you try `var channelId = master.AsQueryable().Where(x => x.Tag == $"{tag}").ToList();` to force execution?

Comment: Just tried your suggestion, i'm still not able to get the channel id value.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202292/discussion-between-barrypicker-and-hfires).

Comment: I'm trying to debug it as we speak. Using some breakpoints.